# How can I use a clean URL only in a subfolder of my website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have a web site http://www.mydomain.com 
 Here I have created a  sub folder http://www.mydomain.com/products. I want to change all the page inside the product folder as clean URL. I know .htaccess should be inside product folder. If it's enabled, will it affect all the parent directories and files of my site

I mean http://www.mydomain.com/ here, will it affect the pages here also.

I have one more doubt about .htaccess file, is there a way I can enable mod_rewrite through any code code without directly editing httpd.conf file

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have one more doubt about .htaccess file, is there a way i can enable mod_rewrite through any code code without directly editing httpd.conf file

You place this line before any rewrite rules in your .htaccess file, which will switch on the rewrite engine - no httpd.conf change required.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

> If it's enabled, will it affect all the parent directories and files of my site

The .htaccess file will only affect the folder it is in and any subfolder of that folder.